# display workflow task custom properties on edit task page only (not on workflow details or task details page) alfresco share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

I need to hide workflow task custom properties from the workflow-details and task-details page and show only on task-edit page.Currently it is visible on all the three pages. 
**abcmodel.xml**

```
<type name="abc:review">
            <parent>bpm:activitiOutcomeTask</parent>
            <mandatory-aspects>  
            <aspect>abc:Info</aspect>
            </mandatory-aspects> 
            </type>
<aspects>
      <aspect name="abc:Info">
         <properties>
             <property name="abc:Det">
             <type>d:mltext</type>
             </property> 
        </properties>
      </aspect>
</aspects>
```

**shareconfigcustom.xml**

```
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="abc:review">
                    <forms>
                         <form>
                            <field-visibility>
                                <show id="abc:Det"/>
                                <show id="bpm:comment" />
                            </field-visibility>
                            <appearance>
                                <field id="abc:Det" label="customproperty" read-only="true">
                                <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                                <control-param name="style">color: black</control-param>
                                <control-param name="rows">6</control-param>
                                <control-param name="columns">6</control-param>
                                </control>
                                </field>
                                <field id="bpm:comment" label="Comments">
                                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl" />
                                </field>
                            </appearance>
                        </form>
                    </forms>
                </config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use form-id to control them.
To hide the field(abc:det) in the workflow details page, you can use like,

```
    <config evaluator="task-type" condition="abc:review">
    <forms>
         <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="abc:Det"/>
                <show id="bpm:comment" />
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <field id="abc:Det" label="customproperty" read-only="true">
                <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                <control-param name="style">color: black</control-param>
                <control-param name="rows">6</control-param>
                <control-param name="columns">6</control-param>
                </control>
                </field>
                <field id="bpm:comment" label="Comments">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl" />
                </field>
            </appearance>
        </form>
         <!-- Form configuration for workflow-details page -->
        <form id="workflow-details">
            <field-visibility>
                <hide id="abc:Det"/>
                <show id="bpm:comment" />
             </field-visibility> 
             <appearance>                               
                .....
            </appearance>
        </form> 
         <!-- Form configuration for task-details page -->
        <form id="task-details">
            <field-visibility>
                <hide id="abc:Det"/>
                <show id="bpm:comment" />
             </field-visibility> 
             <appearance>                               
                .....
            </appearance>
        </form>
    </forms>
</config>
```

I hope you can use, '' to configure the task-details, but I haven't tried it yet.

***Update***
For the task-details, there is no specific form-id is used in `data-form` section. Refer `C:\<Alfresco_Home>\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-data\pages\task-details.xml`

```
  <!-- Data Form -->
  <component>
     <region-id>data-form</region-id>
     <url>/components/form</url>
     <properties>
        <itemKind>task</itemKind>
        <itemId>{taskId}</itemId>
        <mode>view</mode>
        <formUI>true</formUI>
     </properties>
  </component>
```

To customise this task-details form, I added `<formId>task-details</formId>` as mentioned below.

```
  <!-- Data Form -->
  <component>
     <region-id>data-form</region-id>
     <url>/components/form</url>
     <properties>
        <itemKind>task</itemKind>
        <itemId>{taskId}</itemId>
        <mode>view</mode>
        <formUI>true</formUI>
        <formId>task-details</formId>
     </properties>
  </component>
```

You need to use share extension / customisation best practices to change the OOTB files in share. 
[Alfresco Share extensions](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dev-extensions-share.html)

Finally in the share-config-custom.xml file add the configuration like,

```
 <form id="task-details">
    <field-visibility>
        <hide id="abc:Det"/>
        <show id="bpm:comment" />
     </field-visibility> 
     <appearance>                               
        .....
    </appearance>
</form>
```

All set to go and it is working fine to me.

Comment: Sir, it worked well, thanks. but still visible at  "task-details" page.Used the configuration with form id = "task-details"

Comment: path to override file src/main/amp/config/alfresco/web-extension/site-data/pages/task-details.xml